# Hi i have vw polo classic 1.4 2006 when its hot it doesn't wanna start and cuts power while driving

Tags: engine, electrical, head-gasket, water, oil-in-coolant

Help Hi i have vw polo classic 1.4 2006 when its hot it doesn't wanna start and cuts power while driving I changed coil pack and petrol pump and put a new gasket but still continues

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you had the codes read?

Comment: Why have you added the tag “oil-in-coolant”?

Comment: Which gasket have you changed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you checked that the coolant is in good shape? Have you checked that it is not low?

Answer (score 0):

There may be an engine temperature sensor that has failed which makes the ECU think that the engine is cold.  This will be causing an overly rich fuel mixture which could cause hot starting issues and poor running.

Answer (score 0):

Have Seat ibiza 2004 with a 1,4 as well, it's a rebadged VW polo. Had starting issues and long cranking occasionally, it always started when cold but had issues as soon as it got warm.

Turns out it was a faulty coolant temperature sensor. Changed it and the problem went away. I didn't suspect it at first but I did notice after a while I started getting trouble codes related to the coolant temp sensor being out of range. Also I did notice occasionally that the temperature gauge would swing to cold randomly when driving, but that could be caused by a few different things.